# c++ deduce the type of a nested exception

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, c++14, c++17

Introduction:

given:

```
struct X : std::runtime_error {
  using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
```

When we call `std::throw_with_nested(X("foo"))`, what is actually thrown is not an `X`. It is some type that is derived from both `X` and `std::nested_exception`.

therefore, the following assertion will fail:

```
const std::type_info *a = nullptr, *b = nullptr;
try
{
  throw X("1");
}
catch(X& x) {
  a = std::addressof(typeid(x));
  try {
    std::throw_with_nested(X("2"));
  }
  catch(X& x) {
    b = std::addressof(typeid(x));
  }
}
assert(std::string(a->name()) == std::string(b->name()));
```

What I would like to do is deduce that these two exceptions are related.

First attempt:

```
        std::type_index
        deduce_exception_type(const std::exception* pe)
        {
            if (auto pnested = dynamic_cast<const std::nested_exception*>(pe))
            {
                try {
                    std::rethrow_exception(pnested->nested_ptr());
                }
                catch(const std::exception& e)
                {
                    return deduce_exception_type(std::addressof(e));
                }
            }
            else {
                return typeid(*pe);
            }
        }
```

This fails because `std::nested_exception::nested_ptr()` returns a pointer to the next exception down the line, not the `X` interface of the current exception.

I'm looking for (portable) ideas and solutions that allow me to recover the typeid(X) from the 'exception with unknown name' thrown by the standard library during `std::rethrow_exception`.

c++14 and c++1z are fine.

Why?:

Because I want to be able to unwrap a complete exception hierarchy and transmit it across an rpc session, complete with exception type names.

I ideally don't want to have to write a catch block featuring every exception type in the system, which would have to be weakly ordered by derivation depth.

A further example of expected functionality (and an illustration of why my approach does not work):

```
const std::type_info *b = nullptr;
try
{
  throw std::runtime_error("1");
}
catch(std::exception&) {
  try {
    std::throw_with_nested(X("2"));
  }
  catch(X& x) {
    // PROBLEM HERE <<== X& catches a std::_1::__nested<X>, which 
    //                is derived from X and std::nested_exception
    b = std::addressof(typeid(x));
  }
}
assert(std::string(typeid(X).name()) == std::string(b->name()));
```

Comment: @Jarod42 noted, thanks. As you can see, I am using type_index in the code. I'll update the question to compare a and b by name().

Comment: Note sure what you want demonstrate with your last example, you have `std::runtime_error` vs `X`...

Comment: @Jarod42 that's right. The X is wrapping a nested runtime_error. I want to deduce the type of X (the wrapper) from its un-named real type.

Comment: @Jarod42 ok, sorry about that. I have fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around is to consistently use your own `throw_with_nested`, wherein you inject the functionality you want:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <exception>

struct identifiable_base {
    virtual std::type_info const& type_info() const = 0;
};

template<typename Exception>
struct identifiable_exception: Exception, identifiable_base {
    using Exception::Exception;

    explicit identifiable_exception(Exception base)
        : Exception(std::move(base))
    {}

    std::type_info const& type_info() const override
    {
        // N.B.: this is a static use of typeid
        return typeid(Exception);
    }
};

template<typename Exception>
identifiable_exception<std::decay_t<Exception>> make_identifiable_exception(Exception&& exception)
{ return identifiable_exception<std::decay_t<Exception>> { std::forward<Exception>(exception) }; }

// N.B.: declared with a different name than std::throw_with_nested to avoid ADL mistakes
template<typename Exception>
[[noreturn]] void throw_with_nested_identifiable(Exception&& exception)
{
    std::throw_with_nested(make_identifiable_exception(std::forward<Exception>(exception)));
}
```

<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73f87830567f7083)</kbd>

Any time you want more functionality, you can tweak `identifiable_base` and `identifiable_exception` to support what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the conclusion I came to also.

Comment: After rethinking this I decided that it's too much of a burden on users of my code to force them into a nonstandard throw mechanism. I decided on demangling the exception typename and extracting the base type with a regex. At first glance it seems slow, but it only happens at the point of unwrapping the exception so it will be infrequent. Answer provided.

Answer (score 4):

Adapted `print_exception` from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception :

```
const std::type_info&
deduce_exception_type(const std::exception& e)
{
    try {
        std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    } catch(const std::exception& inner_e) {
        return deduce_exception_type(inner_e);
    } catch(...) {
    }
    return typeid(e);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de645d20da836236)

Comment: Note quite. `rethrow_if_nested()` throws the inner exception if present. This function is therefore deducing the type of the deepest non-nest-holder exception in the nested exception chain, not the underlying type of e.

Comment: same problem as per my attempt: "This fails because std::nested_exception::nested_ptr() returns a pointer to the next exception down the line, not the X interface of the current exception."

Comment: @RichardHodges: Can you give example which fails ? For your example, both exception have deduce_exception_type  of `X`.

Comment: Added a test case that demonstrates the issue. Our approaches yield a std::runtime_error because that is the deepest (non-container) nested exception.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the guys who responded.

In the end I felt the most reliable way was to demangle the result of `typeid::name()` and remove any "nested" parts of the typename.

I did have a got at building an exception-registration map, but this then required non-standard throw and rethrow mechanisms to hook into the map.

It's a little platform-specific but it can be encapsulated in a library function:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

namespace
{
    std::string remove_nested(std::string demangled)
    {
#if _LIBCPP_VERSION
        static const std::regex re("^std::__nested<(.*)>$");
#elif __GLIBCXX__
        static const std::regex re("^std::_Nested_exception<(.*)>$");
#endif
        std::smatch match;
        if (std::regex_match(demangled, match, re))
        {
            demangled = match[1].str();
        }
        return demangled;
    }
}
```

my use case (`Exception` is derived from `google::protobuf::Message`):

```
void populate(Exception& emsg, const std::exception& e)
{
    emsg.set_what(e.what());
    emsg.set_name(remove_nested(demangle(typeid(e))));
    try {
        std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        auto pnext = emsg.mutable_nested();
        populate(*pnext, e);
    }
    catch(...) {
        auto pnext = emsg.mutable_nested();
        pnext->set_what("unknown error");
        pnext->set_name("unknown");
    }
}
```

where `demangle()` again is defined in terms of platform-specific code. In my case:

```
demangled_string demangle(const char* name)
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    int status = -4;

    demangled_string::ptr_type ptr {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, nullptr, nullptr, &status),
        std::free
    };

    if (status == 0) return { std::move(ptr) };

    switch(status)
    {
        case -1: throw std::bad_alloc();
        case -2: {
            std::string msg = "invalid mangled name~";
            msg += name;
            auto p = (char*)std::malloc(msg.length() + 1);
            strcpy(p, msg.c_str());
            return demangled_string::ptr_type { p, std::free };
        }
        case -3:
            assert(!"invalid argument sent to __cxa_demangle");
            throw std::logic_error("invalid argument sent to __cxa_demangle");
        default:
            assert(!"PANIC! unexpected return value");
            throw std::logic_error("PANIC! unexpected return value");
    }
}

demangled_string demangle(const std::type_info& type)
{
    return demangle(type.name());
}
```

Where `demangled_string` is a convenient wrapper around the memory returned from `abi::__cxa_demangle` (or similar in windows):

```
struct demangled_string
{
    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)>;
    demangled_string(ptr_type&& ptr) noexcept;
    const char* c_str() const;
    operator std::string() const;

    std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const;
private:
    ptr_type _ptr;
};

demangled_string::demangled_string(ptr_type&& ptr) noexcept
: _ptr(std::move(ptr))
{}

std::ostream& demangled_string::write(std::ostream& os) const
{
    if (_ptr) {
        return os << _ptr.get();
    }
    else {
        return os << "{nullptr}";
    }
}

const char* demangled_string::c_str() const
{
    if (!_ptr)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("demangled_string - zombie object");
    }
    else {
        return _ptr.get();
    }
}

demangled_string::operator std::string() const {
    return std::string(c_str());
}
```